# Why does Power BI table shows ''This table is empty" when data are loaded from a SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I have made a list in SharePoint online and even got succeeded in connecting the SharePoint list with the Power BI desktop via the URL. Once the data are loaded and queried,only the names of the tables are listed down (Only in the query editor but not in the home view) but not any of the columns or data values.It returns that the table is empty.It`ll be a great help if someone could help me with this and Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this same issue, I finally fixed it by updating the data source settings in Power BI desktop for the particular SharePoint connection.

**Go to Data Source Settings -> Select the SharePoint source you're referring to -> Edit Permissions -> Re-enter credentials and log in**

This should allow you to see the data in the list when you refresh the data set. If not, I would suggest checking that the account used to connect to the SharePoint site has proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the applied steps, one of them may cause this error, like some rows getting filtered. Navigate through "Applied Steps" in Power Query editor and find the step where the table becomes empty. Remove that step. This helped me.